# Ros Groovy Installation: Can't find vtk-file

Tags: pcl, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install Ros Groovy on Fedora 19, following http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Fedora. I already had a couple of problems that I have been able to solve myself. However, I don't know how to fix the following problem.

When running

```
sudo ./src_wet/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF --source-space src_wet/ -j1
```

this error

```
pcl/io/include/pcl/io/vtk_lib_io.h:57:29: fatal error: vtkSmartPointer.h: No such file or directory
```

appears. However, the *find* command gives the location of that file as /usr/include/vtk/vtkSmartPointer.h. So, why is this error happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94646/ros-groovy-installation:-can%27t-find-vtk-file/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2013-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a pretty old question, but I thought I'd post an answer. The RIGHT solution is to upgrade to a newer ROS distro, but in the end, it looks like this may simply be an issue of dependencies. I believe that either:

- you need to run `rosdep` to install dependencies for PCL [1]
- you encountered a dependency issue in VTK that has been fixed upstream [2] [3]

[1] http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source#Resolving_Dependencies

[2] https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1057924

[3] https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1080781

---

Originally posted by [cottsay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3167/cottsay/) with karma: 311 on 2014-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2